# How to form mongo query to fetch specific field from array of objects that match a condition

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in my MongoDB and have data in it. I need to write a query that fetches a specific field based on the condition from an array of objects in my collection.

collection each row contains :

```
mouseClicks :[
  {
   "url":"abc.com",
   "moves":{},
   "sitedata":""
  },
  {
 ....
 ....
  } ,...
]
```

I want to fetch sitedata field that matches the specified url.

mongodb version : 4.2.0

```
db.log5.find({'mouseClicks':{$elemMatch :{'url':"first.html"}}},{'mouseClicks.sitedata':1} )
```

I got all the sitedata values from all the documents which are not matching the condition. I expect the output is to fetch only the sitedata for the corresponding url.

Comment: FYI. You're very own choice of question titled entered as a [Google search produces that exact same question and answers as the very top search result](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+form+mongo+query+to+fetch+specific+field+from+array+of+objects+that+match+a+conditio).

Comment: @NeilLunn ,yes it is .but i want only the specified field(sitedata) from the document .That's what i expect .